# is there Youtube API support to retrieve my statistics like if I watched it or not

Tags: youtube-api

is there Youtube API support to retrieve my statistics like if I watched it or not, how many times I played it or retrieve my view history? I spend some time going thru the [Youtube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [YouTube API - ViewCount](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource) to retrieve the number of times the video has been viewed. You can retrieve the information in the client side or in the server side using some of the [libraries](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries).

You need to retrieve the video, from there you can retrieve the `statistics` part contains the `viewCount`

Sample request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=Q5mHPo2yDG8&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Response:

```
200 OK

- Show headers -

{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"g-RLCMLrfPIk8n3AxYYPPliWWoo/dZ8K81pnD1mOCFyHQkjZNynHpYo\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "id": "Q5mHPo2yDG8",
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"g-RLCMLrfPIk8n3AxYYPPliWWoo/4NA7C24hM5mprqQ3sBwI5Lo9vZE\"",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "36575966",
    "likeCount": "127569",
    "dislikeCount": "5715",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "20317"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```